# Inconsistent delta when using requestAnimationFrame and Date.now()

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe

I have a simple snippet:

```
let startTime = -1
let lastNow = -1
let lastTS = -1
const animate = (timeStamp)=>{
  requestAnimationFrame(animate)
  const now = Date.now()
  if(lastTS===-1){
    lastTS = timeStamp
    lastDate = now
  }
  const deltaTS = timeStamp - lastTS
  lastTS = timeStamp
  const deltaNow = now - lastNow
  lastNow = now
  console.log(deltaTS,deltaNow)
}

animate(-1)
```

And I see what i expect, the values are somewhat similar, with the `timestamp` being much more precise

[image]

But, when using this exact code in a massive code base, i see wildly inconsistent results. The delta derived from raf's timestamp is consistent with my refresh rate, the one comparing two `Date.now()` calls varies between 4 and a lot. What could possibly be causing this? I suspect i may have `animate(-)` firing a few times, but i still don't understand why would these be so oddly spaced out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timestamp passed to the callback of `requestAnimationFrame` is, in Chrome and Firefox at least, the time of the last V-Sync signal and in the specs, the time of the beginning of the rendering frame.

All callbacks in the same rendering frame will share the same timestamp.

So what you see here is probably just that your own callback fires after some heavy ones:

```js
requestAnimationFrame((ts) => {
  const now = performance.now();
  const diff = now - ts;
  console.log("first callback", { ts, now, diff });
  while(performance.now() - now < 200) {
    // block the event-loop 200ms
  }
});
requestAnimationFrame((ts) => {
  const now = performance.now();
  const diff = now - ts;
  console.log("second callback", { ts, now, diff });
});
```

Comment: Is there a reason a worker could impact this? Looking at the profiler it seems that most of the animate calls are made at the beginning of the frame, but sometimes there is a tiny task and then a huge gap, making the next two animates much closer.

Comment: I guess a Worker dealing with OffscreenCanvas could have an impact on that, though that would be surprising. More probably, you are seeing the main thread wait for the renderer thread to have done its job committing everything.

Comment: I'm still actually confused. In my case the ts is never the same between these callbacks. Each ts is spaced 16ms apart, so the second callback would log 589.67 if it were somehow setup like my code? (I assume by moving the entire block into the first raf)

Comment: Unexpectedly i got a pretty big diff when doing this. https://codepen.io/pailhead/pen/BaPxmKK

Comment: I'm not sure to follow. My assumption is that you have some other code that also calls `requestAnimationFrame` and which takes some inconsistent time to execute.  I guess you have something like my first callback that gets queued before yours. I guess as a debugging step you could try to replace `requestAnimationFrame = (cb)=>console.trace("called rAF")` and see from where in your codebase it's being called.

Comment: _"And so they found out about this library called `zdog`... thanking the kind stranger, the OP went about their way."_

Comment: Hm, one thing that stabilized it even further was not letting two frames pass by passing in -1, `animate(performance.now()` got me all 16-17 deltas with `Date.now()`. Thank you so much kind stranger!